# c# Class implementation to hold readonly related data (datatable better alternative)

Tags: c#, datatable, implementation, relationship

We have a **static readonly** table of information that we need to consult periodically. The thing is **this data is related** and we need to be able to **get any property using any of the other related properties as index**...

In one or two cases one of the properties could be duplicated between rows but this rarely happens...(see ORDR value in example)

Example:

```
formtypex | objectcode | table | description
  149          23         OQUT     Quotation
  139          17         ORDR     Order
  140          18         ORDR     Especial Order
```

The desired use would be like this:

```
//having one property recover another property the easiest and fastest way possible
string exampleformtypex="149";

string objectcodex=relations.FromFormtypex(exampleformtypex).ObjectCode;

//or a shorter way:
string objectcodex=relations.Find(exampleformtypex, FindMode.FormTypex).ObjectCode;

//or
string objectcodex=relations.Find(exampleformtypex, FindMode.FormTypex, ResultMode.ObjectCode);

//or better
string objectcodex=relations[FindMode.FormTypex, exampleformtypex].ObjectCode;

//or if you can illustrate me with a better aproach
...
```

How would be the class/es definition and methods in order to implement this?

Comment: How much data is in the table?  What is your expected result if I search by table=ORDR

Comment: @Spevy right now there is 23 rows in the table with those 4 columns...in the future there could be 50 rows max and 5 columns...(being static info it will not grow much more)

If you search by table ORDR return first value, or string[] array if passing extra argument maybe? (overloads?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the small data set, your best bet is to create a class (or struct) which holds all your values and load it all into memory

```
public class Relations
{
  public int formtypex;
  public int objectcode;
  public string table;
  public string description;

}
```

You can then put that in a List and use linq to query it.   It is so small that the iterating through the list will not be particularly expensive.

If you want it to be really simple, you can then wrap the functions in a static LookupRelations class.